# Does java escape analysis also work for arrays with only one element?

Tags: java, arrays, escape-analysis

Background:

When you extract methods out of long code pieces, you often run into the call-by-value problem with primitive variables. You cannot change those primitive parameters in the extracted method so that the caller sees the changes.
You can avoid that by making the primitive variable an array with only one element. Then it is effectively used call-by-reference. However it is now an object on the heap. Is the escape analysis of Java clever enough to understand that and use the stack despite that?

Given following code and the case it could not be inlined:

```
public class EscapeAnalysisTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Set<Integer> integers = new HashSet<>();
        integers.add(1);
        integers.add(9);
        integers.add(8);
        integers.add(4);
        // and so on ...

        final long[] product = new long[1];
        final long[] sum = new long[1];
        final long[] count = new long[1];
        final int[] max = new int[1];
        final int[] min = new int[1];

        product[0] = 1L;
        max[0] = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        min[0] = Integer.MAX_VALUE; 

        for (Integer i : integers) {
            calcSomeValues(product, sum, count, max, min, i);
        }

        System.out.println("Product :" + product[0]);   
        System.out.println("Sum :" + sum[0]);   
        System.out.println("Count:" + count[0]);
        System.out.println("Max:" + max[0]);
        System.out.println("Min:" + min[0]);            
    }

    private static void calcSomeValues(final long[] product, final long[] sum, final long[] count, final int[] max,
            final int[] min, Integer i) {
        product[0] *= i;
        sum[0] += i;
        count[0]++;
        max[0] = Math.max(max[0], i);
        min[0] = Math.min(min[0], i);
    }
}
```

Comment: EA is an implementation detail depending not only on the specific JVM but also particular versions and decisions by the JITs. You should write a microbenchmark, enable GC logging, see if it allocates

Comment: I fail to see where escape analysis comes into the picture. If your `calcFactorial()` method becomes hot, it will be inlined. From that point on, there is no method call to worry about, you just create a local variable and update it.

Comment: I was afraid the example would be to simple.

Comment: The problem is that your `calcFactorial()` doesn't allocate anything, so there's nothing that could potentially escape.

Comment: Do not complicate your code by stuffing a primitive into an array so that you can modify it in a different scope. Just *reassign it with the return value*. The entire software industry is trying to move more toward immutability because modifying values across many different scopes makes code harder to maintain.

Comment: You are right. The example makes no sense with only one variable. I added another variable.

Comment: This example makes even less sense now. You're declaring your array variables to be `final` so that they can't be reassigned and then you're mutating them. Additionally, `calcSomeValues` doesn't even have any effect here. It just modifies some local variables; it doesn't return values or modify shared data. This all flies completely in the face of Principle of Least Astonishment.

Comment: *"Then it is used call-by-reference"* No, it isn't.

Comment: Effectively, it is used call-by-reference then. Arrays can only be passed call-by-reference as they are objects.

Comment: @mmirwaldt That isn't entirely true. "Pass by reference" usually means that the *value in the outer scope* can be directly modified. You can't actually modify the variable in the outer scope here, though. It passes the value of a pointer, which allows you to modify data on the heap. But the actual variable on the stack can't be modified. Forcing the value out on the heap doesn't change how the runtime passes values into a method.

Comment: I am afraid you miss the point of my question and get confused by my (bad) example. I have changed my example again. The arrays are passed as parameters now. THIS SITUATION CAN OCCUR AND CANNOT ALWAYS BE AVOIDED BY USING IMMUTABLES OR RETURNING VALUE OBJECTS OR SO ON. Please focus on my question and not so much on my example. ;-)

Comment: I've made an update that I think improves on the example code I originally provided. I also want clarify that I don't think I missed the point. Rather, my analysis was that what you were trying to do was fundamentally ill-advised, regardless of the answer to your exact question. So my immediate response was to provide that advice. I think the suggestion I provided is easy enough to adapter to similar situations, without the odd usage of `final` single length arrays being mutated.

Comment: Although your example has become incredibly complicated, you **still** don't do any allocation in the called function, therefore asking about escape analysis still doesn't make sense.

Comment: "I found that array objects only benefit from escape analysis when the size is 64 or less."  in http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue179.html

Answer (score 2):

Here's a better way to do this:

```
public class Test {
    public static class Summary {
        private long product;
        private long sum;
        private long count;
        private int max;
        private int min;

        private Summary() {
            product = 1;
            sum = 0;
            count = 0;
            max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            min = Integer.MAX_VALUE; 
        }

        public long getProduct() { return product; }
        public long getSum() { return sum; }
        public int getCount() { return count; }
        public int getMax() { return max; }
        public int getMin() { return min; }

        public static Summary summarize(Collection<Integer> ints) {
            Summary s = new Summary();

            s.count = ints.size();
            for (Integer i : ints) {
                s.product *= i;
                s.sum += i;

                if (i > s.max) {
                    // You can use Math.max if you want
                    s.max = i;
                }
                if (i < s.min) {
                    // You can use Math.min if you want
                    s.min = i;
                }
            }

            return s;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Set<Integer> integers = new HashSet<>();
        integers.add(1);
        integers.add(9);
        integers.add(8);
        integers.add(4);
        // and so on ...

        Summary s = Summary.summarize(integers);

        System.out.println("Product: " + s.getProduct());
        System.out.println("Sum: " + s.getSum());
        System.out.println("Count: " + s.getCount());
        System.out.println("Max: " + s.getMax());
        System.out.println("Min: " + s.getProduct());
    }
}
```

Using arrays the way you have is just weird. Don't do it. This will confuse other programmers and isn't how the language is intended to be used. It violates the Principle of Least Astonishment.

Instead, find a way to make the system work for you without going into weird territory. You have multiple values that are logically associated with each other, and they're all computed at the same time. When you have several values that are used together, it's a good time to think about using a class. By using a class and a single method that does all the updating, your code is clear and sensible. The class I've provided actually ends up being immutable (as far as external code is concerned) because the logic of computing the summary is all inside the `summarize` method, which has access to the private attributes, so it's very well encapsulated. (The names could probably be better, but I think this is good enough as an example.) If modifying the private state in `summarize` is undesirable, this can be easily adapted by giving `Summary` arguments with the values of its instance variables and simply passing the values into the constructor after computing them as local variables, which would turn `Summary` into a very simple result object.

Keeping all this logic very localized and preventing callers from modifying the result makes it very easy to reason about what's going on. Your example code with length one arrays violates both of those principles and makes it harder to understand, use, or maintain the code.

Alternately, if you can use the values immediately after calculating them, you can skip the class and just calculate them all in line. You could do this via a loop or calculate them separately using built in functionality.